# How can I enable AHCI on a SATA drive after installing Windows?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, sata, pata, ahci

Can I enable AHCI after installing Windows 7 in a SATA drive that was on IDE mode?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to make the `msahci` and/or `IastorV` drivers be loaded early.

(Note: For Windows 10, the built-in driver is called `storahci`.)

---

According to [Microsoft KB 922976](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/922976), run [Fix it 50470](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9741862) or open **regedit**, navigate to one of these keys:

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\msahci`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\IastorV`

and set the value of the `Start` dword to 0.

[image: using regedit to enable AHCI mode in Windows 7]

Reboot and enable AHCI in BIOS, now it should work.

Remember to create a restore point before any changes, just in case.

---

The same registry changes can be done via Cmd, using `reg add` or `sc config`:

- Check current parameters (and make sure the service exists):

  ```
  sc qc msahci
  ```
- Change the boot mode:

  ```
  sc config msahci start= boot
  ```

  (Note that `start=` is a single parameter, but `boot` is separate.)

Comment: It only worked when I followed your procedure.