# Throughput issues on newly built PC (according to Windows Experience Index)

Tags: windows-7, ssd, motherboard

I recently built a new PC running Windows 7 on an SSD and am surprised to see my Primary Hard Disk - Disk Data Transfer Rate scoring at a 5.9.

My motherboard is a GIGABYTE GA-Z77X-UP4 TH and my SSD (which the OS is installed on) is a Samsung 840 Series 2.5 inch 120GB SATA III.

From everything I have looked at I should have a score in the 7.x range for this combination of hardware based on the fact that I am using the SAT III port for the SSD.  I have used Samsungs software to make sure I am on the current firmware and am unsure as to what I need to look at from a BIOS perspective to determine if my configuration is optimal.

Any help would be appreciated, please let me know if there is additional detail necessary to identify the issue.

Edit - Here are the current scores coming out of Samsung SSD Magician . . .
Seq Read: 526 MB/s
Seq Write: 132 MB/s

Random Read: 82,449 IOPS
Random Write: 32,925 IOPS

Comment: What is the SATA setting in the BIOS?  Should be AHCI, but may be on legacy (IDE) or Raid.  However, the WEI is relatively arbitrary.

Comment: WEI might be mistakenly consider a HDD your primary hard drive. Whatever the reason is, there is no problem to solve here. It doesn't matter how fast WEI *thinks* your SSD is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For WEI, it may be best to reset the results so that you system show as "Unrated" and then rerun the assesment. I agree with you that your primary HDD data transfer results should be nearing the max 7.9 mark with your equipment.

To [reset WEI score](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/79177-windows-experience-index-reset.html) at sevenforums.com has listed out an easy tutorial.

Other thoughts would be to ensure that you have enabled AHCI in BIOS and double check in widows. Should see this in your device manager [image: AHCI] You can follow one of a few suggestions here in SU [like this one](https://superuser.com/questions/110927/enabling-ahci-on-sata-drive-in-windows-7). Double check your SATA connections and that you are on the grey SATA ports on your board, never hurts to recheck the obvious

Comment: After reviewing my BIOS settings and version I ended up updating the BIOS and resetting the WEI score.  I did not change any BIOS settings but the combination of BIOS update and recreating the WEI score resulted in a 7.9 score for the SSD.  Thanks for your help.