# Windows 10 install does not recognize SSD

Tags: windows-10, drivers, ssd, sata

I have a Workstation HP Z440 still under warranty.

The hard drive was replaced with an SSD drive and it's not under warranty.

Now I have to reinstall Windows 10 Pro on the new SSD drive, which is already installed and recognized by the BIOS.

When I do the Windows 10 installation, Windows does not recognize the drive.

I've been told that I need the SATA drivers for windows 10, but I can't find where they are in the page of Workstation HP Z440 drivers.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved.
Instead of looking for drivers, I went in BIOS and set sata as ide.
Installation went fine.

Comment: Be in mind putting your SSD as a IDE drive might reduce its performance. You can check this topic [How can I enable AHCI on a SATA drive after installing Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/110927/how-can-i-enable-ahci-on-a-sata-drive-after-installing-windows)