# windows 10 installer and debian 10 installer do not recognize SSD

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, debian, bios

I'm trying to reinstall Windows 10 and Debian 10 on a new Acer Aspire 5 (A515-56G) but I can't. The laptop came with Windows 10 Home ed. x64 already in it and it is working fine.
None of the installers (both on USB prepared with Rufus) can detect the hard drive during installation.

I'm aware of this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1465611/windows-10-install-does-not-recognize-ssd) and many other procedures I found on other forums (a long list of them, I didn't track them all).
I updated the BIOS drivers with the last version according to some posts I read. It didn't help.
The BIOS starts on UEFI mode and I have no other way to change it.

Disabling the secure mode doesn't help.
Just in case it helps, the partition style is GPT.
I am able to install Debian 10 to another usb stick but not to the internal SSD hard drive.

I would appreciate any help and suggestions on how I can install any OS on the internal SSD.
Thank you

Edit after @Ramhound's question: Here's a screenshot of the Rufus settings:
[Rufus settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doaL2.png)

Comment: Have you tried creating a Windows 10 DVD? You can download the Windows 10 for free.

Comment: What tool are you using to create the installation media for Windows?  If you are using Rufus provide a screenshot of the options you used

Comment: @vssher: no, I didn't try creating a DVD. I have at the moment no DVD burner.

Comment: @Ramhound: I didn't take a screenshot of the options but I remember them very well; here they are: I let Rufus download the OS (Windows 10 home, release 20H2, english international, x64)
Image option: Standard Windows installation
Partition scheme: GPT
Target system: UEFI (non CSM)
File system: NTFS
Cluster size: 4096
Quick format: yes
Create extended label and icon files: yes
Check device for bad blocks: no

Comment: @neanderbot - I would try using the Media Creation Tool instead of Rufus, I cannot verify those options are correct, without a screenshot of the interface

Comment: @Ramhound: I just tried with the Media Creation Tool from MS but it didn't recognize the internal drive either.  I tried again with the Rufus software and I edited the OP with a screenshot of the settings.